# Running SQL Statement from Bash or Perl Script?

Tags: sql-server, bash, perl, jdbc, odbc

I am wanting to write a Script, either Perl or Bash, where I can run one or more ***Select*** SQL statements to get some info off a Database on a Remote Server.

Currently I can use GUI Tools like RazorSQL and DbVisualizer to connect to the Database and view Tables, run SQL commands, etc... But, I want to try and run some SQL commands from a script so I can use the results from the cmds in a Bash/Perl Script.

The Server running the Database has the following details:

- **Operating System:** Microsoft Windows Server 2003 RS Standard Edition SP2
- **Database:** Microsoft SQL Server 2005

When connecting to the Database using RazorSQL on a Windows PC, my connection uses the Driver **"net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"**.
Then, when using DbVisualizer on my linux box I use the JDBC Driver **"SQL Server (jTDS)"**, both of which seem to work just fine.

So in an attempt to try this from Perl I downloaded the following Packages:

- unixODBC
- FreeTDS
- SQSH ---> **however, I could not get it compiled because of Sybase...*
- The Perl Modules: DBD::ODBC, DBD::JDBC, DBI

To install, test and setup unixODBC I used this site: http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_1.html
And used this site: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/UserManual/, to add DSNs...

Now I attempted to use these directions here: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/perl.htm, to connect to the Database from Perl, but I am having some trouble getting it to connect.

Could anyone tell me if I am on the correct path for this, or what my connect() string should look like...? In RazorSQL the JDBC "URL" looks like this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.2.200:1433/ActiveDB;appName=RazorSQL;useCursors=true
```

And I'm confused as to how to use a DSN I created with the GUI command **ODBCConfig** from within the Perl Script... I'm having trouble finding a real-life example for connecting to MS SQL Server in Perl.

The file listing the Drivers looks like:
**odbcinst.ini**

```
[MySQL ODBC 3.51.27r695 Driver]
Driver      = /usr/lib/unixODBC/libmyodbc3.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/unixODBC/libmyodbc3S.so
UsageCount  = 1

[JDBC/ODBC bridge driver for java-1_6_0-sun]
Driver      = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/libJdbcOdbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0/jre/lib/i386/libJdbcOdbc.so
UsageCount  = 1

[TDS Driver]
Driver      = /usr/lib/unixODBC/libtdsS.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/unixODBC/libtdsS.so
UsageCount  = 1

[net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]
Driver      = /opt/jtds-1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1.jar
Setup       = /opt/jtds-1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1.jar
UsageCount  = 1
```

**The last one in this list is the same Driver used by RazorSQL, but since it's a jar file I guess it can only be used with Java programs...*

And this is in **~/.odbc.ini**

```
[MyDB]
Driver      = /usr/lib/unixODBC/libtdsS.so
Description = 
SERVER      = serverName.foo.bar.local
PORT        = 1433
USER        = user1
Password    = abc123
Database    = ActiveDB
```

Given that, how should my "connect()" string look in Perl, and would that be the right Driver to use...?

I'm new at attempting this with a Script, and my head is currently spinning with information.... So ANY help someone could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of browsing through the DBD::ODBC documentation, I found some examples. [This one](https://metacpan.org/source/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.52/examples/DbiTest.pl) does the following (I removed some parts, this is not a literal quote).

```
my $dsn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$options{DbSrcServer};DATABASE=$options{DbSrcDatabase};NETWORK=dbmssocn;UID=$options{DbSrcLoginName};PWD=$options{DbSrcPassword}";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$dsn") || die "DBI connect failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;      # enable transactions, if possible
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 0;
$dbh->{PrintError} = 1;      # use RaiseError instead
$dbh->{ShowErrorStatement} = 1;
```

Unfortunately, there are no real explanations in the driver's docs, so lets go with that. We know that there is a `DRIVER=` and a `SERVER=` and so on. Those are also present in your *odbc.ini*, so you should try them.

```
my $dsn = "DRIVER=/usr/lib/unixODBC/libtdsS.so;SERVER=serverName.foo.bar.local;PORT=1433;DATABASE=ActiveDB;UID=user1;PWD=abc123";
```

**Disclaimer**: I cannot test this, and I have no idea if it works. It's just an educated guess that I would try.

---

You can also try using DBD::JDBC, which sounds relatively easier. [This part of its docs describe the dsn](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-JDBC/JDBC.pod#Connecting-to-the-server). But you need a few dependencies. I believe you have covered some of them already though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply simbabque, I really appreciate the help..! That didn't exactly work. I was getting an error on the DBI connect line saying: "failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002)"... So this got me thinking, and I replaced the entire `$dsn = "..."`, with just the name of the DSN, \*i.e. "[MyDB]".. So I had `my $dsn = "MyDB";`. And this time the command took a long while to eventually fail, and I got a different error this time: "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104"

Comment: Why would it try to connect to MySQL? Aren't we talking about a Microsoft sql server?

Comment: I attempted to use each of the Drivers that I had added to the ODBCConfig GUI, which are written in odbcinst.ini... And that one seemed like it had gotten a little bit further then the others, the driver for that test was the *"/usr/lib/unixODBC/libmyodbc3.so"* one which I'm seeing now is for MySQL not SQL Server. My bad...

Comment: I'm going to give **DBD::JDBC** a try and see if I can get that one to work... I'll comment back shortly... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty... I believe I have this working. Thanks again simbadque for suggestions, I VERY much appreciate you taking the time to assist!

I had gotten so mixed-up and turned-around during all of this, I wasn't even sure which way was UP anymore... So, I decided to ignore everything I did so far and start looking at this again. And I ended up finding an EXCELLENT guide someone wrote up for doing exactly what I wanted to do *(*shocker...)*!!

I found these instructions on *PerlMonks.org* at the link below *(*I know the title is pretty obvious)*:
**Accessing Microsoft SQL Server from Linux using DBD::Sybase** --> http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=392385

Basically, in short, I needed to do the following:

1. **Uninstall FreeTDS:** I needed to do a `make uninstall` in the source directory where I originally compiled/installed it from...
2. **Re-Compile & Re-Install FreeTDS:** reconfigured freetds using this as the configure command --> `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --with-tdsver=7.0`.
3. **Configure FreeTDS.conf** *(*after `make install`)*: Added the following lines to the config file:
   `try server login = yes
   try domain login = no
   tds version = 7.0`
   These lines make it so it uses the Database login creds and NOT the Windows Domain login info. And tds version 7 tells freetds what version to connect to the DB with, and read that version 7 is for SQL Server versions newer then *MS SQL Server 2000*...
4. **Create a Server Entry in *freetds.conf*:** I added the following lines to add my Server running the MS SQL Server 2005 Database.
   `[mydb]
       host = jwp-eim02.paoli.jwpepper.local
       port = 1433
       tds version = 8.0`
5. **Test "mydb" Entry:** `/usr/local/freetds/bin/tsql -S mydb -U sqlUsername`
   After running that command I get prompted for a password and then I get a command prompt that looks like **"1> "**, which tells you it logged-in successfully.!
6. **Finally, Test in Perl:** **Below is the sample code I used to get data from the SQLServer Database...*

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use DBI;

   $dsn = 'DBI:Sybase:server=mydb';

   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "sqlUsername", 'sqlUserPwd');
   die "unable to connect to server $DBI::errstr" unless $dbh;

   $dbh->do("use DatabaseName");

   $query = "Select * from EXAMPLE_TABLENAME";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare ($query) or die "prepare failed\n";
   $sth->execute( ) or die "unable to execute query $query   error $DBI::errstr";

   $rows = $sth->rows ;
   print "$row rows returned by query\n";

   while ( @first = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
       foreach $field (@first) {
           print "field: $field\n";
       }
   }
   ```

I then executed that Perl Script and VIOLA...!! I got data back from the Select Statement!

Hopefully this helps someone else looking to do the same thing... And I guess if I wanted to do this with something like Bash, I could probably use one of the commands that came with FreeTDS, like tsql, osql, etc... But, I'm not positive about that.